# Confidence level for OpenCV TLD tracker

Tags: c++, opencv, tld

I am using the TLD implementation in OpenCV for a project for identifying similar targets within an image. These targets are similar enough for the tracker.update() to always return true. Is there a way of getting the raw values it is using for its comparison to other targets, or even better an indication of how confident the tracker is on each match?